# Data types use in Matlab functions

Tags: matlab, function, types, casting, type-conversion

I am new to Matlab. I have this function which I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between two pixels(RGB).

```
function[distance]=calc_dist(R1, R2, G1, G2, B1, B2)

    if (R1>R2)
        dR=R1-R2;
    else
        dR=R2-R1;
    end

    if (G1>G2)
        dG=G1-G2;
    else
        dG=G2-G1;
    end

    if (B1>B2)
        dB=B1-B2;
    else
        dB=B2-B1;
    end

  sum=uint64(3*dR*dR+4*dG*dG+2*dB*dB);
  disp(sum);
  distance=(sqrt(double(3*dR*dR+4*dG*dG+2*dB*dB));
end
```

The problem is the displayed value for sum is 255 each time. This must be happening because the variables are of type uint8. How do I change them? I tried to do some sort of casting

```
sum=uint64(3*dR*dR+4*dG*dG+2*dB*dB);
```

but I get this error: 'Undefined function 'uit64' for input arguments of type 'uint8'. How should I display the right value for the sum? Thanks.
'

Comment: Don't even cast, just do the math. I also don't know why each of those terms should be multiplied - you are computing the Euclidean distance, no?

Comment: and for the record matlab has built in `dist()` which should be able to calculate distances using several metrics

Comment: @Ben With no casting, the output is 255. Each time.

Comment: The function to cast as a 64-bit unsigned integer is `uint64`; you were just missing the `n`.  Be that as it may, the casting is occurring too late - after you have done the multiplication and not before.  You may want to try something like `R1=double(R1)` etc. for each input variable (tedious) and then set the Euclidean distance as `dist = sqrt((R1-R2)^2 + (B1-B2)^2 + (G1-G2)^2)`.  (Not sure where your 2,3 and 4 come in.)

Comment: @GeoffHayes Tedious, indeed. It gets the job done, though. Thanks. Isn't there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider converting your input of 6 variables to one 2x3 matrix, where the first row is the RGB colours from one pixel, and the second row is the RGB colours from the second pixel:

```
function[distance]=calc_dist(R1, R2, G1, G2, B1, B2)

rgbPixels = [R1 G1 B1; R2 G2 B2];

% cast as double
rgbPixels = double(rgbPixels);

% compute the difference between the rows
rgbDiffs = diff(rgbPixels);

% compute the Euclidean distance
distance = sqrt(sum(rgbDiffs.^2));
```

This way, you don't have to change your signature and all casting can be done in one line.  Try the above and see what happens!